# How to do a MySQL query with 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following database structure:

```
season             prices             room_categories    
---------------    ---------------    ---------------
id                 id                 id
name               season_id          name
date_from          category_id
date_to            price
```

There are several seasons / prices for each room category and I need to find a query which joins those 3 tables like in the following example:

```
season              room_categories     prices 

                    id -------------->  category_id
id ---------------------------------->  season_id
```

What would be the best way to create such an query?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way would be using `JOIN`s.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO lol sir you made my day, I know I shouldn't comment chatty things but I just couldn't help it

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

A query like this will help.

```
SELECT * FROM season AS t1
LEFT JOIN prices AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.season_id
LEFT JOIN room_categories AS t3 ON t2.category_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id = '?'
```

Enjoy, don't forget to tip the geek.